# RStudio freezes when using dplyr

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, freeze, r, rstudio

For the last two weeks, **RStudio** very often freezes when I enter **dplyr** commands interactively in the console or running them manually from the code window. No such issue in RGui or (I think) when running a script using source(). The problem seems to occur mostly when there's an error in syntax. The RStudio diagnostic report does not log these crashes.

I'm running R 3.5.2, RStudio 1.2.1256 (the same problem occurred in 1.1.463) and dplyr 0.7.8. My computer runs 64bit Windows 10 (fully updated), AMD Radeon HD 5700 with 2 monitors (I've read about similar issues related to multiple monitors but none of the solutions were applicable).

When the error occurs, RStudio R Session eats up a lot of CPU:

[Task Manager View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0rkg.jpg)